# How can Android PreferenceFragment display preferences in dual pane format, like the PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-4.2-jelly-bean

The PreferenceActivity can display headers on the left pane and corresponding preference fragments on the right pane. I currently have the preference fragment loaded via the tab listener, i.e. the preference fragment is pulled up and inflated into the current view when the preferences tab is clicked. I would rather not load another activity by way of the preferences activity as it disrupts the "flow of content". But the preferences activity can display headers in one pane and corresponding preferences on the right pane, for example - on https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHnbv.png .

How can a preference fragment display headers and corresponding fragments in dual pane format?

I'm using Android 4.2.2

Comment: Check out this training: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedFragments (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)